# Handling concurrent writes with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency

I'm working on an application that was written using Fluent NHibernate. It's a .Net MVC application and right now i'm running into the following issue: when two users are performing the same operation (i.e. booking the same appointment at the same time) it seems that the application is not doing the checks fast enough in order to see that the time slot has already been booked.

I've got very limited experience with NHibernate and all I can tell you is that at this moment the NHibernate Session's transaction isolation level is set to ReadCommitted; the session lifetime I assume that it is set to PerWebRequest (I have yet to find the part of the code that does this).

I know this is very little information but can anyone please at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you checking for existing booking on the timeslot just before trying to save? You'll probably need to do that manually.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it right by using the transaction object inside the session. I'm calling "session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommited)" before I start performing the checks and at the end I'm calling "session.Transaction.Commit()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NHibernate docs have a full chapter dedicated to [Optimistic concurrency control](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-optimistic)

In a nutshell, by adding a version field, NHibernate can automatically detect if the code is trying to modify a record that's been changed by another session after being read. After that, you can retry, show an error message, etc.